# Ascii represantion of compressed data without certain character

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I want to process a large number of pickled data with Hadoop using Python. What I am trying to do is represent my data as some key (file id) and compressed pickle as value in a large file.

If I simply try to put binary code as ascii in the file which I want to process with hadoop I am getting a lot of '\t' and '\n' values which interfere with (key, value) structure of hadoop file.

My question is: how can I compress some data using python and represent it as a string in an ascii file avoiding certain characters (such as '\t' and '\n')?

Or maybe my approach is inherently invalid?

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the pickled object to `base64` using the `base64` module.

Answer (score 0):

For compression you could use the `zlib` or `bz2` modules. For representation you can use the `base64` module.